# Nested async function inside forEach loop. Why doesn't the outer function await for an await call from the inner function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

**Example:**

- OUTER **async function**

  - INNER **async function**

    - **await** call()

I can see that the **OUTER does not await for an await call from the INNER**. But can somebody explain this to me so I can fully understand **why it works like that?**

```js
const someArray = [
  {foo: 'bar1'},
  {foo: 'bar2'},
  {foo: 'bar3'}
];

function callMockAPI_1() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(someArray),500);
  });
}

function callMockAPI_2(item,delay) {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve('API_2 responded: ' + item.foo),delay);
  });
}



async function main() {                    // OUTER ASYNC FUNC
  console.log('Calling mockAPI_1...');
  const myArray = await callMockAPI_1();
  myArray.forEach(async (item) => {        // INNER ASYNC FUNC
    const newItem = {...item};
    console.log('This is item: ' + item.foo);
    if (item.foo === 'bar1') {
      const result = await callMockAPI_2(newItem,1500);  // INNER AWAIT CALL
      console.log(result);
    }
    else if (item.foo === 'bar2') {
      const result = await callMockAPI_2(newItem,1000);  // INNER AWAIT CALL
      console.log(result);
    }
    else if (item.foo === 'bar3') {
      const result = await callMockAPI_2(newItem,500);  // INNER AWAIT CALL
      console.log(result);
    }
  });
  
}


main();
```

Comment: Use `for..of` instead of `forEach` if you want them to run in serial, or `.map` and `Promise.all` for parallel

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you. The duplicate does answer my question. Should I delete this one?